# Представление Backbone.View не успевает получить данные с сервера

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, firebase

Использую Backbone.js и облачный сервис Firebase (+Backbonefire).
Клик по ссылке изменяет хэш в URL.
Router обрабатывает хэш: в зависимости от значения создает экземпляр новой страницы (т. е. страница остается прежняя, но динамически меняется содержимое). Например, www.myapp.com/index.html#statistics.

```
Page.create('StatisticsPage');

function create(type) {
    try {
        removeCurrentPage();
        require(['pages/'+type], function (Page) {
            currentPage = (new Page()).render();
        })
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('Unknown Page - ' + type);
    }
}
```

Т. е. после создания экземпляра страницы вызывается render(), который в свою очередь вызывает renderComponents().

```
render: function () {
        this.$el.append(this.renderComponents());
}

renderComponents: function () {
        var components = this.components,
            $html = $();
        for (var i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
            var component = components[i];
            $html = $html.add(component.render().$el);
        }
        return $html;
    }
```

`this.components` содержат в себе представления отдельных составляющих страницы: панель управления (button, select, input) и таблица. Получаем коллекцию, передаем ее в представление, представление записываем в массив компонентов. Происходит это в `currentPage = (new Page()).render();`, до рендера.

```
var itemCollection = ItemsControl.getItemsCollection();
        var itemsView = new StatisticsView({
            collection: itemCollection
        });
        this.components.push(itemsView);
```

ПРОБЛЕМА: рендер отрабатывает раньше, чем данные синхронизируются с сервером. Можно, конечно, в представлении повесить на событие "sync" обработчик и вызывать рендер, но получается, что это уже будет второй вызов. Как-то не очень.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала получи данные, потом рендери вьюху.

```js
var promise;

promise = $.ajax({<Здесь конфиг запроса к серверу>});


promise.then(function(data) {
   var view = new yourClassView({params: data});
  
  // Дальше ты делаешь с вьюхой все что надо, если у тебя
  // marionette то вставляешь в регион, если чистый бекбон,
  // то уже твоя вставка в DOM
});
```